# Simplifying the code to calculate probability of tossing 4 unfair dice

Tags: list-manipulation, probability-or-statistics

> Four identical unfair dice are tossed once. Find the probability of events in which the sum of numbers (facing up) is 18. Given the probability of face 6 is $1/2$ and that of each other face is $1/10$.

## My attempt

```
ClearAll[data,prob]
data = DeleteCases[Tuples@Table[Range[1, 6], 4], x__ /; Total@x != 18];
prob = (# /. {p_ /; p != 6 -> 1/10, 6 -> 1/2}) & /@ data;
Times @@@ prob // Total
```

with output $12/125$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
pd = EmpiricalDistribution[({1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 5}/10) -> Range[6]];
Probability[Total[Array[x, 4]] == 18, Thread[Array[x, 4] \[Distributed] pd]]
(* result 12/125 *)
```

Answer (score 3):

Without filtering:

```
Total[Times @@@ Map[If[# == 6, 1/2, 1/10] &,
                    Flatten[Permutations /@
                            IntegerPartitions[18, {4}, Range[6]], 1], {2}]]
   12/125
```